# Bash command (if statement) Terminal

Tags: macos, bash, if-statement, terminal

I have the following question:

```
if [ (airport en1 -s|awk 'END{print NR—}’) -lt 11]; then
    open  ~/Desktop/1-10.mp3
else if -ge 10 -lt 15
    then ~/Desktop/11-14.mp3
else if -ge 14 -lt 18
    then ~/Desktop/15-17.mp3
else if -ge 17 -lt 21
    then ~/Desktop/18-20.mp3
else if -ge 20 -lt 24
    then ~/Desktop/21-23.mp3
else if -ge 23 -lt 27
    then ~/Desktop/24-26.mp3
else if -ge 26 -lt 30
    then ~/Desktop/24-27.mp3
else if -ge 29 -lt 36
    then ~/Desktop/30-36.mp3
else if -ge 35 -lt 41
    then ~/Desktop/36-40.mp3
fi
```

Basically I want it to scan how many wifis there are `Airport en1 -s)`
Then I let it count without the first line `|awk 'END{print NR—}’`
and then I have a series of if commands which I all need to get a more sensitive result. But it is not working right now.

Can anybody help me out please?
(and yes I already read a bash tutorial ...)

Comment: What about it is "not working"?  For one thing, to execute a command and use its result you want `$(...)` not just `(...)`, and also watch out for "smart quotes" like it seems you might have in the first `if` since those don't parse right in `bash`, and also you need a space before the closing `]`, white space there is not optional.  Also, look at `elif` instead of all those nested `else if` which would each need a closing `fi`

Comment: Among other problems, you seem to be assuming that the second and following comparisons will implicitly use the value from the first. They won't.

Comment: Ok I see what you mean. But how can I do that then?

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a lot of issues even in this much of the code (the remainder just repeats the problems shown here):

```
if [ (airport en1 -s|awk 'END{print NR—}’) -lt 11]; then
    open  ~/Desktop/1-10.mp3
else if -ge 10 -lt 15
    then ~/Desktop/11-14.mp3
```

- The `]` is a separate argument to the `[` command; spacing in the shell is crucial.
- The `’` should be a single quote (apostrophe) `'` (noted by [Eric Renouf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4687135/eric-renouf) in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34256510/bash-command-if-statement-terminal/34257143#comment56254796_34256510)).
- The `else if` should be spelled `elif`.  As written, you'll need an extra `fi` for each `else if`.
- The system probably does not provide a command `-ge` which you're trying to run.
- The second and subsequent commands are not prefixed by `open`.
- And in the first line, the `(` is wrong as written.  It looks as though you had in mind something like:

  ```
  if [ $(airport en1 -s | awk 'END {print NR}') -lt 11 ]; then
  ```

  This runs a command `airport` with two arguments and sends the output to `awk` which prints the number of lines it read.
- Using `awk` to count lines instead of `wc -l` might be regarded as overkill.  It will, however, work.
- You appear to have an em-dash `—` after the `NR`; that probably isn't valid at all.  I'm not sure if you intended a `--` (double dash) or something else.  A `--` would probably be syntactically valid, but functionally pointless (there's no point in post-decrementing a number if you'll never use it again).
- Your boundary conditions are a bit suspect too.
- The erratic groupings (10, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 6, 5) are a little odd, too.  Note that you attempt to run `24-27.mp3` for what might be expected to be `27-30.mp3`, and you run `30-36.mp3` for what might be expected to be `31-36.mp3`.

Maybe you really need:

```
num_mp3=$(airport en1 -s | awk 'END {print NR}')
if [ "$num_mp3" -le 10 ]
then open ~/Desktop/1-10.mp3
elif [ "$num_mp3" -le 14 ]
then open ~/Desktop/11-14.mp3
elif [ "$num_mp3" -le 17 ]
then open ~/Desktop/15-17.mp3
…
fi
```

Note that the testing won't reach the `elif` if the number is less than or equal to 10, so there's no need to repeat the boundary test in that condition.

Comment: WOW this is amazing! As you probably guessed I am pretty new with coding, so this is great to learn from.
Now the only more thing I want is that it repeats this code automatically every 10 seconds.

Online I found this:

watch -n 10 num_mp3=$(airport en1 -s | awk 'END {print NR}')
if [ "$num_mp3" -le 10 ]
then open ~/Desktop/1.mp3
elif [ "$num_mp3" -le 14 ]
then open ~/Desktop/11-14.mp3
elif [ "$num_mp3" -le 17 ]
then open ~/Desktop/15-17.mp3
…
fi
but that does not work

Comment: I don't know what the `watch` command does (it isn't on my Mac).  You'd probably need to put the assignment and conditional into a shell script (say `~/bin/run-mp3.sh` if you have made yourself a `bin` subdirectory), make sure it is executable (`chmod 755 ~/bin/run-mp3.sh`) and then do something like `watch -n 10 ~/bin/run-mp3.sh` to run it.  I don't have an `airport` command in my path either; maybe you're running the Airport Utility from the command line somehow — or maybe what you're running is wholly unrelated to the Mac's Airport networking.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: `watch(1) - execute a program periodically, showing output fullscreen`.  Use-cases are similar to cases where you'd use `tail -f` on a log file, but it shows the whole output every time.

Answer (score 0):

Capture the output into a variable so you can do different tests on it

The if statements all need valid stand-alone commands

Comment: How do I do that if I already have a counting command?
$(airport en1 -s | awk 'END{print NR--}')

Comment: @shirin sorry for the lame answer, trying out posting from my mobile.  Capture into a variable instead of the first if

Comment: No problem though, I appreciate any help. I am trying to put the scaning and counting into a variable 
s='airport en1 -s |awk 'END{print NR--}''
as soon as I click enter I get an error 
zsh: command not found: NR--}